# AngularJS: How load partial view from server side?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-routing

I am working on the Java based web application build on Spring MVC. Now in this application I am trying to integrate AngularJS framework, to attain modular client side code and also to decouple my client site modal and view.

In Spring MVC as we are returning ModelAndView from our Controllers, here I am trying to using this returned view with the AngularJS router module.

```
var hmAdministration = angular.module('administration', ['ngRoute']);

hmAdministration.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
        when("AngularJSSpringMVC/displayRoleList", {templateUrl: "AngularJSSpringMVC/displayRoleList"});

});
```

Now here ***AngularJSSpringMVC/displayRoleList*** is a URL binded to controller API which is returning 
ModalAndView.
Now as per my understanding the view that is getting returned here should be placed at my **`<ng-view></ng-view>`** tag.
When I run this code complete client side it is working, but now trying this code to integrate with SpringMVC, seems like whole lots of dots still needs to be connected.

Comment: `whole lots of dots... connected` ? Great technical explanation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, AngularJS **always** run `complete client side`.

You didn´t specify your errors, so I´m guessing here, based on my own experience when integrating Angular with MVC Views.

Please note that the address on your browser should look like this:
`http://yourserveraddress/#/AngularJSSpringMVC/displayRoleList`

The `#` is important, that´s what differentiate between Angular routing and your MVC routing (done in the server). The above address will load your index page, and your angular code should be in it, which will process the route after the `#` and make it all work.

You are right when you expect that the content of your MVC view should be loaded on your `ng-view`.

A suggestion would be to use different enough routes in angular so that they cannot be easily confused, maybe something like this would make it simpler:

```
$routeProvider.
    when("displayRoleList", {
        templateUrl: "AngularJSSpringMVC/displayRoleList"
});
```

So your url would be `http://yourserveraddress/#/displayRoleList`.

I hope that can be helpful, if I missed the mark badly, please share some more code.